# Electric Standing Desk

Tags: electrical, stepper-motor

So, I'm trying to build an electric standing desk for myself. I drew what I have in mind as a guideline for my questions here.

Basically I want a desk that varies in height from 65 to 130. I imagined (actually saw some standing desks at salles) with 3 stages, pink, green and blue. The red block would be a motor that rotates the orange spindle (don't the correct names in english) and "push or pull" the lilac "screw", therefore moving the green stage aswell. There's two gears connectiong the orange and pink spindles, so the green and pink stages move together, expanding and contracting.

I would need two of this structure, they would be the table feet.

My questions are

Will this work? Knowing it must support 120 kilos or more. What kind of motor should I use? This structure can be "sealed" or will I have to do maintenance, such as oiling the gears, etc...

[image: Project Idea]

Comment: Why screws? One design option is to use a cable wound onto a drum, geared down…

Comment: For the pink stage you mean? I called the lilac piece screw, but is actually a nut..

Comment: for motors, just buy linear actuators (dc motors with screws).  there are telescoping leg motors that will come with some type of encoder already built in.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about those kind of motors, they solve really easy the first step, pushing and pulling the green part, now I have to solve how to move the pink one, hehe

Comment: Most telescoping legs will get you just a bit shy of 1:2 min:max length.  If you want closer to 1:3, just mount two of them to each other (side by side), with one extending up and the other extending down.

Comment: Is it correct to say that if a linear actuator can push 150kg it can also sustain it? And what about the design with gears for the pink stage to move together with the green one? In this case using a linear actuator for the first stage..